# Transparent background for WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my app I wish to make the WKWebView with transparent background, so the view behind (an ImageView) can show through as background picture.

```
    webView!.opaque = false
    webView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

The code above works fine with UIWebView, but if webView is WKWebView, a white background will be shown.

Also tried putting transparent background color in CSS. The result is the same, only works in UIWebView but not WKWebView. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 90):

For iOS 10+ using Swift:

```
self.webView = WKWebView()
self.webView!.isOpaque = false
self.webView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.webView!.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: WKWebView.scrollView.backgroundColor is by default clear color already.

Comment: isOpaque and background must be set after the content has been loaded for this to work, for example in `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)`.

Comment: @Andreas, For me, it worked by setting them directly in Interface Builder, no need to defer them.

Comment: It doesn't work on iOS 13.0 (it works on iOS 13.3 at the same time).

Answer (score 40):

This code might help you. Updated for Swift 3+

```
self.webView = WKWebView()
self.webView.isOpaque = false
self.webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 12):

```
using objective c.
wkWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
wkWebView.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
wkWebView.opaque = false;
```

It will remove the white background colour in wkwebView.

Answer (score 7):

**WKWebView for macOS with Objective-C**

This is the magic line for transparent WKWebView views within macOS.

```
[webView setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey:@"drawsTransparentBackground"];
```

Comment: man 36 points, you deserve more. your solution is nice.

Comment: setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key drawsTransparentBackground.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Uncheck `Opaque` checkbox in Interface Builder

**Update July 2021, Xcode 13**

Looks like the checkbox is still there

[image]

Comment: There is no `Opaque` checkbox, just `Hidden`.

Comment: @ErikAigner I just checked Xcode 13, it's still there. See update

Comment: Yeah seems to be only available on iOS, although `WKWebView` exists on both.

Answer (score 5):

This bug seems to be fixed in Beta 5.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a very old question. But I've been struggling with this today. I don't know if it's just me, but webView.backgroundColor was undefined in WKWebView, and webView.opaque was read-only. The only way for me to fix this was to set the web views layer background color to the CGColor clear

```
webview.wantsLayer = true
webView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor
```

and the containing NSView the same way

```
webViewParent.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor
```

That's the only thing that worked for me, I hope it could help someone else as well.

Comment: the question is about iOS, not OSX

Comment: its not even working on OSX

Answer (score 4):

Code below works for me:

```
 [wkWebView setValue:YES forKey:@"drawsTransparentBackground"];
```

Comment: SetValue:YES is disallowed with ARC. [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] should be use. And also  there is no key value coding-compliant drawsTransparentBackground for the WKWebView

Comment: @InnaKamoze thanks. Could you please provide another solutions that works?

Comment: If these method's  not working , something is smashes WKWebView properties or another problem exist. Anyway there is no such a method as  drawsTransparentBackground and setValue ForKey not supported for ARC

Comment: Thanks, this realy works for me. No problem with SetValue as NSNumber.. your example is ok!

Comment: This crashes the app on iOS 13.0.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't worked with WKWebView yet but even UIWebView used to have this issue and the solution was to wrap the html content inside something like this:

```
<body style="background-color:transparent;"></body>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, tried it, and also putting color: transparent; in css file, also does not work. The background is always white.

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading a PDF and want a background color different than the standard gray, it seems that it is necessary to wait until the document is loaded, then clear the backgrounds of the subviews. The advantage of using a `WKWebView` over a `PDFView` (iOS 11+) is that `WKWebView`s have double-tap to zoom and a page count indicator built in, and are compatible with older versions of iOS.

It should be noted that it's not a great practice to dig into system views like this as Apple can change the implementation at any time, potentially breaking the solution.

Here is how I implemented a PDF preview controller with a black background in Swift 4:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?
    var url: URL

    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
            webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
            webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        self.observer = webView.observe(\.isLoading, changeHandler: { (webView, change) in
            webView.clearBackgrounds()
        })

        webView.loadFileURL(self.url, allowingReadAccessTo: self.url)

    }
}

extension UIView {
    func clearBackgrounds() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        for subview in self.subviews {
            subview.clearBackgrounds()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need exactly what you described. But unfortunately your solution isn't working on iOS 12. I still have a little 50% gray border around my pdf document...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help, but i used this solution below:

```
func setBackgroundWhite(subviews: [UIView]) {
  for subview in subviews {
    subview.backgroundColor = .white
    setBackgroundWhite(subviews: subview.subviews)
  }
 }
```

This does recursive call inner in subviews, setting up the background to white, or another color.

I used this code when loading PDF files, `WKWebView` and iOS 10+

Comment: Are you able to change the PDF background color from white to anything? When I try this it changes all background colors but PDF is still white.

Comment: Are you speaking about background color from document?

Comment: Yes. When I load a PDF in my webview, the PDF document has a white background. There are apps that can change the style of the PDF document (background color and font colors) and I was seeing if the code above was a possible route to do this.

Comment: Any ideas? @Tiago Amaral ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to change background-color to transparent in Styles and delete an App from phone/simulator manualny - it looks that WKWebView Cache HTML / Styles