# How can I duplicate the UIScrollView's bounce animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

These bounce animations really bother me:

1. When you drag your finger from the top.
2. When you scroll towards the top with a hight velocity and you lift your finger.

I tried with physics but it's just not as smooth. The code below derives from classical physics. Where:

Force = Mass * Acceleration

Acceleration = Velocity / Time

Velocity = Distance / Time

The constant is Force / Mass.

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

        NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {

            CGFloat constant = 10000.0;
            CGFloat velocity = (contentOffset.y - _lastContentOffset.y) / (timeInterval - _lastTimeInterval) * -1;
            CGFloat time = velocity / constant;
            CGFloat distance = powf(velocity, 2) / constant;

            CGFloat minimumDistance = 0;
            CGFloat maximumDistance = (self.frame.size.height - minimumDistance) * (1 - PHI) * PHI;

            if (distance > maximumDistance - minimumDistance) {

                distance = maximumDistance - minimumDistance;
                time = distance / velocity;
            }

            NSLog(@"Velocity: %f", velocity);
            NSLog(@"Time: %f", time);
            NSLog(@"Distance: %f", distance);

            [UIView animateWithDuration:time
                              delay:0
             usingSpringWithDamping:1
              initialSpringVelocity:1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^{

                                 _webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, distance, _webView.frame.size.width, _webView.frame.size.height);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                 [UIView animateWithDuration:time
                                                   delay:0
                                  usingSpringWithDamping:1
                                   initialSpringVelocity:1
                                                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                              animations:^{

                                                      _webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _webView.frame.size.width, _webView.frame.size.height);
                                              }
                                              completion:nil];
                         }];
        }

        _lastContentOffset = contentOffset;
        _lastTimeInterval = timeInterval;
    }
```

Is there any other way except creating a UIScrollView?

**EDIT**: I'm trying to make WKWebView bounce even if bounce is turned off. I turn bounce off and then implement my own bounce methods. Also, the WKWebView has some weird bouncing behavior, so staying with the default UIScrollView isn't an option.

**EDIT 2:** Here's 2 videos showing the difference between the WKWebView and UIWebView scrolling:

1. UIWebView: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juyN_B8ba48
2. WKWebView: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLEH9rnwYVU

Comment: What are you trying to create the animation in? Also, it seems like you are using a scroll view already? Also, why not just use the scroll view animation itself. If you want to "animate" something that isn't in the scroll view you can always use the changing content offset of the scroll view to make it look like you're animating something else.

Comment: I can't use the default UIScrollView because it's bounce property is turned off which means that when it reaches top it's contentOffset remains (0, 0).

Comment: What? Just turn on bounce?

Comment: Hmm... dunno. Sounds like you're creating a lot of work for no reason. I don't really understand the problem fully but it seems like UIScrollView is what you are looking for. Except you said that you're not. **Note** WKWebView content is displayed in a UIScrollView so the bounce should just work. What about it is "weird"?

Comment: WKWebView is NOT bouncing correctly but let's not argue about that.

Comment: Let's argue exactly about that. The root problem here is `WKWebView` not bouncing properly. Ask a question about that instead of asking about reinventing `UIScrollView`.

Comment: I'm not arguing about anything. Just trying to understand what "weird" is. If I knew what you meant by "weird" then I might know how to make it not "weird". But it's not a very descriptive word.

Comment: I uploaded 2 videos on youtube showing their difference.

Comment: `WKWebView` is in beta, perhaps it's worth filing a bug report to see if the difference is intentional. http://bugreport.apple.com. I believe that is a much saner approach than trying to "fix" it yourself.

Comment: Maybe it's not a bug. Maybe it's the new way. It's currently Beta 4 and nothing has changed.

Comment: Is the difference in the way the header doesn't follow the content?

Comment: Yes. In fact there are 2 differences, the first is the one you mentioned and the other is the background which remains white and can't be changed to any other color: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687257/transparent-background-for-wkwebview

Comment: It seems like the difference you're seeing might be in how UIWebView and WKWebView are rendering the page slightly differently, in terms of which parts of your document are scrollable vs fixed?

Comment: Videos not working :(

Comment: Abandon ship! I tried so many things to get this to work but it is always incomplete. It might look like it's working but it's not Apple-like. WKWebView hasn't changed since.