# How to make transparent background WKWebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, transparent

I want a transparent web page in swift, so I have tried the below code according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687257/transparent-background-for-wkwebview). Still, I am not getting a transparent web page. nothing changes in webview colour.. may I know why??
where am I going wrong? please help me in below code.

Total code:

```
 import UIKit
 import WebKit
 class WebviewViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var testWebView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    guard let url = URL(string: "https://developer.apple.com/swift/") else { return }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    testWebView.load(request)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

          self.testWebView = WKWebView()
          self.testWebView!.isOpaque = false
          self.testWebView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
          self.testWebView!.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
}
```

Please help me with the code.

Answer (score 2):

the code to make transparent background is as follow what you already added.

```
self.testWebView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

now question is you added right code already then why you are not getting reliable output ..?

Also , if you try
`self.testWebView!.alpha` with any value, it will affect all of `WebPages` as `WkWebView` is a single view and changing it's alpha will also affect the components within...

it happened because the page you load in WebViewController has some `HTML` and `CSS` code, you make your WebViewController transparent but because of that `HTML` &`CSS` you can't see it's transparency as each `webpage` has it's own background color settings (which is merely impossible to change for each `webpage`)

I hope you will understand and it will help you ...:)

Comment: yes you are correct.. then how can i get transparent web page.. ?? can't we achieve with swift code?? suggestion please

Comment: to achieve you have to make change in HTML & CSS file of each and every loaded url-page which is very difficult process and also if you do like this then it will effect your speed ... that's  why I will they that is nearly not possible ... :(

Answer (score 0):

as I see, you use storyboard (`@IBOutlet`) and you can use Storyboard for setting your `WKWebView`:
[image]

And about code. This is enough for the result. You shouldn't set again `self.testWebView = WKWebView()`, because you use storyboard and you can set `isOpaque` with storyboard. As result:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let url = URL(string: "https://developer.apple.com/swift/")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        let js = "(function() { document.body.style.background='transparent'; })();"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(js) { (_, error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

and `evaluateJavaScript` helped to add transparency for background:
[image]

Comment: yes i am using storyboard to add webview, as you mentioned i have clear webview B.C, still not getting transparency

Comment: I've updated code with implementation `transparent` for `background`

Comment: I tried like above: I clear the background color for webview, and I added your code.. here func webView()  is calling.. but nothing change.. I didn't get transparent background

Comment: did you complete all the settings in the storyboard (allowed execution of js code) and use the same url? I've tested my code only with your url and attached the result in the last screenshot. You are probably not fully configured